# javascript Maps

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

Is there any way where in I can map a "javascript Map" into a "Java Map"???? I mean that i have an array of key value pairs in my javascript of a page. Is there a way where in i can get this map in my  spring controller using an Ajax call????? If yes, how will the function argument corresponding to this map be????

Comment: If you are able to convert an `Array of key value pair Arrays` into java map then you can convert your js map by `[... mapVar]` to something like this: `[[k1, v1], [k2, v2], .... ]`

Answer (score 1):

Convert your JavaScript objects/arrays into a single [JSON](http://json.org/) string (using `toJSON()`), and then send that string to your controller. Use one of the available [Java JSON parsers](http://www.json.org/java/) to convert the JSON string back to something pleasant in Java.

Comment: Can you please show an example here???? I wish to know how the controller function will look like.

Comment: If i convert the map into JSONString, what should the correspoding argument type for this be in controller???? Should it be a String only???

Comment: There is plenty of sample code, depending on which Java JSON library you use. Your controller will be receiving a string value as part of your AJAX request. (All HTTP parameters are strings as they go over the network, even if they look like integers or dates or booleans to you and me.)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert JavaScript Maps (e.g. JSON objects) into a plain Java format by using a JSON library such as [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/), and then liberally "match" the keys and their values to a Java map to test for "sameness".

Answer (score 0):

suppose that you have an array with key value pair array name is Holidays
 now you want to get holidaysIds from holidays
so ,

`var HolidaysIds=Holidays.map(function(value) {return value.holidaysId;});`